# Basic https proxy squid

Tags: proxy, squid

I read that squid was one of the easier proxy to configure but I have some issues.

The server is on aws ec2

I followed this tutorial https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-in-ubuntu/

Changing `http_port 3128` to `http_port 3128 transparent`

And

`http_access deny all` to `http_access allow all`

But I have

```
ERROR: NF getsockopt(ORIGINAL_DST) failed on local=xx.xx.xx.xx:3128 remote=xx.xx.xx.xx:62780 FD 10 flags=33: (92) Protocol not available
ERROR: NAT/TPROXY lookup failed to locate original IPs on local=xx.xx.xx.xx:3128 remote=xx.xx.xx.xx:62780 FD 10 flags=33
```

I also tried to add

```
acl localnet src XX.XX.XX.XX
```

where XX.XX.XX.XX is my ip

Or also

```
acl localnet src all
```

But I always have the same issue

I just want to sent request to an api having a static ip, do not konw if setting up squid is a good solution.

I already tried with nginx, it was working good but I made some update to my code and not working now

I am open to all solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Squid is enough complex to configure.

My recommendation is to use Netgate [PfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) if it's getting provided by Amazon ec2.
By having the Pfsense installed, you will be provided with a nice & simple web interface to manage and install/configure your squid proxy. for your type of required service, the web GUI is more than enough, but if need more customizains, you have a full SSH access to the OS itself to configure the Squid server configuration directly.